# Should my API functions take shared_ptr or weak_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I am currently designing an API and I am not sure whether my functions should take `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr`. There are widgets that contain viewers. The viewers have a function `add_painter` which adds a painter to the viewer. When a viewer needs to redraw, it uses its painters to draw into a buffer and displays the result. I came to the conclusion that the viewers should hold the painters using `weak_ptr`:

- A painter may be used in multiple viewers, so the viewer cannot own the painter.
- Deleting the painter should remove it from the viewer. This way, users do not need to remember that they have to call a `remove_painter` function.

There may be different kind of viewers, so they are hidden behind an interface. What signature is best for the `add_painter` function in the interface?

Should I directly use `void add_painter(weak_ptr<Painter> const& p)`? This implies that the concrete implentations store the painters using `weak_ptr`, but I cannot enforce this: An implementation could just do `painters.push_back(weak_ptr.lock())` and store a `shared_ptr`.

Should I use `void add_painter(shared_ptr<Painter> const& p)` instead? This implies that the viewers hold strong references, so that deleting a painter does not necessarily remove it from the viewer.

I also considered storing the painters directly in the interface class, but then it is no real interface anymore, is it?

Comment: I'd say https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this question.

Comment: Okay, should I reask it there or can you move it somehow?

Comment: Easier if you move it. Software engineering isn't on the vote to move list, so you'd have to wait for someone with vast godly might to migrate it. That said, I think it's a reasonable fit for this site. Far as I'm concerned, this is a good question even if it might be crossing into opinion based. I want to see what some of the gurus bring to the table. I don't have anything concrete on this one, so I'd just be opinion and I'm going to shut up now. What the heck am I doing up anyway? At this hour any advice I gave would be questionable at best.

Comment: No, this was just my personal suggestion. Maybe you consider the SE section next time. Anyway, +1 for a good question.

Comment: Why does your API use `shared_ptr` on the first place? `shared_ptr` implies worst possible ownership pattern, which typically can be avoided.

Comment: @VTT In the question I give reasons for `weak_ptr`. And using `weak_ptr` means using `shared_ptr` somewhere else.

Comment: I mean avoiding both `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. It seems that people often use `shared_ptr` to "be on the safe side".

Comment: @Kane when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to mitigate the Observer pattern with smart pointers and definitely you should avoid a situation when a client (View) can harass the server by converting the weak pointer to a shared pointer and storing it indefinitely barring it from being released by the server.

You should really consider the classic Observer pattern here requesting View to provide a `painter_destroyed` callback function. It may be an annoyance but also gives the client an opportunity to implement some additional actions once the painter is destroyed. Otherwise finding that the painter exists no more just when one wants to use it may be quite irritating and affect overall program performance.

Comment: This means that I have to invert the relationship between viewer and painter, right? Instead of calling `add_painter` on the viewer I do something like `add_viewer` / `add_observer` on the painter.

Comment: I think it remains up to your taste. add_painter  may return a pointer to callback function

Comment: This function should be called before the painter is destroyed, giving  the observer a chance to gracefully cease to access it. Naming it e.g. `on_destroying_painter` would be more logical then. (Sorry for stating the obvious.)